# How do I print the repeated items in a list without printing the first occurrence?

Tags: python, list

In a `list = [1,2,1,1,1,2,3,4]` I would like to print the output as `[1,1,1,2]` which is to print the duplicates in the list without printing the first time they occurred in python.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Also, I imagine you may have been typing pseudo code, but don't name lists 'list'.

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution is to define a function which uses `set` to track seen items. If an item is not seen, add it to the set. If it is seen, yield that item.

If you wrap this in a generator, you have the benefit of making this process lazy, which is useful with large lists when you only need to iterate results.

```
lst = [1,2,1,1,1,2,3,4]

def dups(x):
    seen = set()
    for i in x:
        if i not in seen:
            seen.add(i)
        else:
            yield i

res = list(dups(lst))

[1, 1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve that would be:

```
a = [1,2,1,1,1,2,3,4]
read_so_far = set()
result = []

for val in a:
    if val in read_so_far:
        result.append(val)
    else:
        read_so_far.add(val)

print(result)
```

> [1, 1, 1, 2]

Comment: You should use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) instead of a list for the `read_so_far` variable. That makes membership testing O(1) instead of O(n).

Comment: You are right, Aran-Fey. The reason I'm using a list is for simplicity. If someone is asking this question, probably knows how a list works, but has not heard of a set yet.

Comment: Well, now would be a good time to learn about sets. It's not like they're rocket science. SO exists to educate people, doesn't it?

Answer (score -1):

```
from collections import Counter

original_list = [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]

c1 = Counter(original_list)
c2 = Counter(set(original_list))

c1.subtract(c2)

print(list(c1.elements()))
```

Comment: This indeed does return `[1,1,1,2]` for this particular example, but this is only because all `1`s happen to come before the duplicate `2`. If you try it with `[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 23, 4]`, it does not preserve the order. But I don't know, maybe the OP didn't want to preserve the order... (I'm not the downvoter, have no real opinion on that. You might consider to add a comment, though).

Comment: original_list = [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 23, 4] return [1, 1, 1, 1, 2] - is this expencted result?

Comment: jpp's solution preserves the order. For example for `[1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,3,4]`, it outputs `[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]`.

Comment: you are wrong, the code returned a value [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]. Example: https://repl.it/repls/MediumorchidNeglectedBetaversion

Comment: That's not jpp's version, that's your version.

Comment: What version is it? You did not even check my code and started criticizing it

Comment: I meant [jpp's version, the currently most upvoted answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50156060/2707792). If you run jpp's version on `[1,2,1,2,1,2]`, it will output `[1,2,1,2]` (preserves order). Your version, when run with input `[1,2,1,2,1,2]`, outputs `[1,1,2,2]` (does not preserve order). My intent was less to "criticize" your answer, but instead to add a comment that it does something meaningful, so it doesn't get deleted too quickly (your answer ended up in the "low quality posts"-review queue, probably because there was a downvote and no explanation of the code).